# iis management console

Tags: iis, dotnetnuke

I install IIS management console in win 7 ultimate :

[image: IIS Management Console]

when i click on OK button after several minute i receive this error :

[image: Error]

and after restart the OS this feature not install.

When i use INETMGR command in run box the service not found error Occurs.
inetmgr.exe not exist in its location. how to solve this problem.

Comment: may be you have to register it with dot net framework using `Aspnet_regiis` tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read these two pages carefully and please be aware of messing up everything because you don't know the answer, it just makes everything worst. Do exactly as they say and everything should be fine. Also let me know the result please.

In my opinion, check the relevant values under `"Internet Information Services"`. When you did not check the `"IIS Management Service"` what do you want with `"IIS Management Console"` anyway?! Without the service console only can connect you to the remote IIS servers and nothing else will happen.

Cheers

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754865(v=ws.10).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725762.aspx

Also you can run this command as an Administrator as the second document says:

```
start /w pkgmgr /iu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;IIS-StaticContent;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-HttpErrors;IIS-HttpRedirect;IIS-ApplicationDevelopment;IIS-ASPNET;IIS-NetFxExtensibility;IIS-ASP;IIS-CGI;IIS-ISAPIExtensions;IIS-ISAPIFilter;IIS-ServerSideIncludes;IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics;IIS-HttpLogging;IIS-LoggingLibraries;IIS-RequestMonitor;IIS-HttpTracing;IIS-CustomLogging;IIS-ODBCLogging;IIS-Security;IIS-BasicAuthentication;IIS-WindowsAuthentication;IIS-DigestAuthentication;IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication;IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication;IIS-URLAuthorization;IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-IPSecurity;IIS-Performance;IIS-HttpCompressionStatic;IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic;IIS-WebServerManagementTools;IIS-ManagementConsole;IIS-ManagementScriptingTools;IIS-ManagementService;IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility;IIS-Metabase;IIS-WMICompatibility;IIS-LegacyScripts;IIS-LegacySnapIn;IIS-FTPPublishingService;IIS-FTPServer;IIS-FTPManagement;WAS-WindowsActivationService;WAS-ProcessModel;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI
```

Comment: TanX _[Pawan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/400876/pawan)_  and _[Moahmmad](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1623728/mohammad-goudarzi)_ I had multiple .NET Framework version installed in my laptop because of vs2012 . I remove theme (version 4.5) and reinstall one of them (version 4).

Comment: Cheers body, happy to hear that. Good luck.